# Create a button to export in treeview as CSV

Tags: python, excel, csv, tkinter

I am trying to create a button that can export a data to CSV and I am facing some problems.

My data frame is df1.
if there is no data uploaded, the code will show a message box : "No Data", " No data available to export". otherwise, it should save the data in the location that I specified using the function
"**filedialog.asksaveasfilename**"

```
def export():
    global df1
    if len(df1) < 1:
        messagebox.showerror("No Data", " No data available to export")
        return False
    fln = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir=os.getcwd(), title="Save CSV", filetypes=(("CSV File", "*.csv"),("All Files","*.*")))
    
    with open(fln, mode='w') as myfile:
        exp_writer = csv.writer(myfile, delimiter='\t')
        for i in tv1.get_children():
            row = tv1.item(i)['values']
            exp_writer.writerow(row)
    messagebox.showinfo("Data Exported", "Your data has been exported to " +os.path.basename(fln)+" sucessfully.")
```

The error that I got is:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Mahmoud Khadijeh\Desktop\Python2\Python\FTIR.py", line 344, in export
    with open(fln, mode='w') as myfile:
TypeError: open() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mode'
```

Any help!

Comment: Can you provide a/the value for `fln`? (as returned from the filedialog, not expected value)

Comment: @NickSlash 
The value of fln is C:/Users/Mahmoud Khadijeh/Desktop/111

where 111 is the name of the file that I saved. However, the file will not appear in this directory

Comment: Is that the complete function for `export` in your question, are there any more lines?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!
I used a different way to export the data and here is the function

```
def export():
    global df1
    if len(df1) < 1:
        messagebox.showerror("No Data", " No data available to export")
        return False
    fln = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir=os.getcwd(), title="Save CSV", filetypes=(("CSV File", "*.csv"),("All Files","*.*")))
    print("fln== ", fln)
   
    types = filename
    gifs_and_pngs = []
    for type in types:
        this_type_files = glob.glob(type)
        gifs_and_pngs += this_type_files
    
    df1 = pd.DataFrame()
    for excel_file in gifs_and_pngs:
        df2 = pd.read_excel(excel_file, header= None)
        df1 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis = 1)
          
    df1.to_excel(fln+".xlsx")
    messagebox.showinfo("Data Exported", "Your data has been exported sucessfully.")        
        
    

expbtn = Button(root, text="Export CSV", command = export, bg='snow', highlightthickness = 1, bd=3)
expbtn.place(rely=0.66, relx=0.265)
```